# How to Invoke below script block using Invoke-parallel

Tags: powershell

This Invoke-Parallel is taken from [here](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Parallel.ps1)

Below is my script block

```
$scriptblock ={
get-service -ComputerName $parameter.computername | where {$_.name -eq $parameter.serviceName }
}
```

below is a custom object

```
$pscustomobject = @()

$pscustomobject += [pscustomobject]@{
Computername ='server1'
Servicename ="service1"
}

$pscustomobject += [pscustomobject]@{
Computername ='server2'
Servicename ="service2"
}
```

I tried using Invoke-Parallel using below method ,but this doesnt work

```
Invoke-Parallel -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -Parameter $pscustomobject

"server1","server2" | Invoke-Parallel -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -Parameter $pscustomobject
```

Few services exist in few servers and on few others,they dont,so created a custom object which tightly maps services to servers.

Any ideas would be greatly helpfull

Comment: That looks like it should work, what happens when you try it?  Does it just run in serial?

Comment: this looks like it runs the code in parallel **_on the source system._** have you looked at the built in `Invoke-Command` stuff yet? that can run things _on the targets_ ... and thus in parallel. it can run faster since it uses the remote systems to run each scriptblock and then send the results back

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what is the advantage of `Invoke-Parallel` over the ThreadJob Module? Or for the purpose of running different commands on remote servers, using at the same time `Invoke-Command` with `-AsJob` as @Lee_Dailey pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Parameter` switch makes the properties available to each item in the script block.  I think if you make a small modification like this, then it should work:

```
$scriptblock ={
   $thisServer = $_
   $thisServerParams = $parameter.Where({$_.Computername -eq $thisServer})
   get-service -ComputerName $thisServerParams.computername | where {$_.name -eq $thisServerParams.serviceName }
}
```

We can use this code above to find the right properties we should use for each server.  With the code before, we were effectively using `Invoke-Parallel` to run the same command on all servers each time.  And the logic wouldn't work for matching services in the `Where` block because it would compute to

```
$pscustomobject.ServiceName
service1
service2

PS C:\Users\Stephen> $pscustomobject.ServiceName.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                       
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                       
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

An individual service coming back from `Get-Service` would never equal to System.Array

Comment: Wouldn't you need to remove single-quotes around `$thisServer`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Foxdeploy,found one more way to achieve what i need,below method is more flexible for me,since..when i pass two services,one service may take a lot of time to start or stop and may hold data from another service as well

```
$pscustomobject | Invoke-Parallel   -ScriptBlock {

 $computername = $_.computername
 $servicename = $_.servicename

get-service -ComputerName $($computername)  | where {$_.name -eq $($serviceName) } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I believe this would be faster, using builtin Powershell cmdlet and also looks cleaner imo:

```
$servers=@(
    'server1'
    'server2'
)

$scriptblock={
    switch($env:COMPUTERNAME)
    {
        'server1'{Get-Service service1}
        'server2'{Get-Service service2}
    }
}

$result=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
```

Edit:
For the sake of demonstration, here I'm waiting 10 seconds and then resolving a easy mathematical equation on 7 servers depending on their name 3 pairs of them start with the same name. If this was a linear invocation it should've taken 10+10+10+10 seconds yet it only took 15 seconds for all of them. This demonstrates that you can execute different commands on different remote computers at the same time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unless you use `-as job` , these commands run one computer at a time

Comment: See example 7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Not sure what you read on MS Docs but I'm pretty sure this is totally possible. You can see my edit if in doubt. @TheGameiswar